# Arithmetic overflow in Fortran

Tags: fortran

I am working with `REAL` numbers like `4*10**11`, and the compiler complains that the numbers are too big, it says

> Error: Arithmetic overflow at (1)

I tried to use `REAL*8` and `REAL*16`, but this does not solve the problem

How can I solve this problem?

A MWE could be this:

```
  INTEGER nioni
  REAL fg,t,num,c1,minimo,massimo,en0,alpha,func
  fg=0.047214

  t=0.00000015

  num=3688100.
  c1=5.30
  minimo=0.469185*fg*t
  massimo=7.4*10**11*fg*t

  DO nioni=1, 10
   en0=(0.1+(20.-0.1)*rand())
   func=num*(1./(en0+c1)**c2)*en0**c3*fg*t
   alpha=minimo+(massimo-minimo)*rand()
   DO WHILE(alpha.gt.func)
    en0=(0.1+(20.-0.1)*rand())
    func=num*(1./(en0+c1)**c2)*en0**c3*fg*t
    alpha=minimo+(massimo-minimo)*rand()
   WRITE(*,*) en0
   END DO
  END DO
```

Comment: You really have to show the [mcve]. There are plenty of Q/A about this in general, we cannot repeat all that.

Comment: I am guessing Fortran tries to evaluate `10**11` as integer, and causing overflow.  You could use `4.0 * 10.0 ** 11`, or better yet `4.0E+11`.   First one uses real*4 to calculate the value.  Second one is literal expression for 400000000000.0 .

Comment: @yosukesabai using 400000000. actually solved the problem thank you

Comment: Similar ones to yosukesabai... 4.0D11 defines the number in 64-bit...